# Satellite Radio OEM location on an 2009 Acadia

Tags: audio, installation, gmc

Does anyone know how to get at the XM unit on an '09 GMC Acadia?  I can **see** the unit.  It's located on the inside of the trunk, above the rear, driver-side tire.  However, there's a large, black piece of plastic covering it.  Any help or links to a detailed manual would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding manuals here: http://sm.gpona.com:9001/si/home.do

Select the Acadia and then drill down through: Service Manual > Driver Information & Entertainment > Cellular, Entertainment, Navigation > Repair Instructions > Digital Radio Receiver Replacement.